# How to fetch the distinct of a column in pyspark delta table and update the same to all the rows

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a delta table as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6PlQ.png)

i need to pick similar_partnumbers for each VehNum , find the distinct of similar_partnumbers values,concat them  and update the same for all rows of that vehicle under distinct Control_circuit

required result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL1dW.png)

How to achieve this using pyspark delta table

tried couple of options but didnt get the results expected

Comment: Your description does not fit to the image of your result: Do you want to select all similar_partnumbers for each VehNum or for each VehNum+Control_Circuit as shown in your image of the required result ?

Comment: @gregor   i want to select all distinct similar_partnumbers for each VehNum+Control_Circuit and add them to similar_partnumbers column(concatinating distinct similar_partnumbers)

Comment: @gregor , can you help me with this